# Why Disallow Special Characters In a Password?

Tags: password-management, databases, sql-injection, password-policy

The culprit in this case is a particular (and particularly large) bank that does not allow special characters (of any sort) in their passwords: Just [a-Z 1-9].  Is their any valid reason for doing this?  It seems counter productive to stunt password strength like this, especially for a system protecting such valuable information.

The only thing I have been able to come up with is a weak attempt to thwart SQL injections, but that would assume the passwords are not being hashed (which I sure hope isn't true).

Comment: even encryption means nothing character wise, modern encryption operates on the binary level. However I'll let you consider banks and the like that ask for x, y and z characters from password...

Comment: By special characters are you referring to ASCII special characters like `,./<>?;':"[]{}\|!@#$%^&*(-=_+` or unicode characters `€`, `£`, `♥` as p____h's answer suggested?

Comment: Ally Bank does not recommend special characters in your password if you going to access your account via android. Completely stupid. At least standard characters like a ? should be allowed.

Comment: Sometimes, no technical reason. See this great (and hilarious) response to a similar question about password length: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/what-technical-reasons-are-there-to-have-low-maximum-password-lengths

Comment: [Here's another very similar question on a sister site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/87366/are-there-any-valid-reasons-for-disallowing-characters-and-limiting-the-length-o)

Comment: Plot twist: On every website, I use the same I-think-it-is-strong-because-it-has-symbols password with a `$`, `=` and `@` character. Your bank just prevented me from using the same password everywhere.

Answer (score 76):

One explanation I haven't seen here is that many financial institutions are tightly integrated with older systems and are bound to the limitations of those systems.

The irony of this is that I have seen systems that were built to be compatible to older systems but now the older systems are gone and the policy still must exist for compatibility with the newer system that was built to be compatible with the older system.

(the lesson here is that if you have to be compatible with an old system, allow for some future elimination of those limitations).

Comment: This is a major problem with security. +1 for pointing out one of the biggest flaws in IT security at least in my opinion.

Comment: Of course, this means that the passwords are not stored in a hashed format.  If they were hashed then even older systems would not be an issue.

Comment: That's probably a good part of the  explanation... it's ironic and sad.

Answer (score 15):

What about the support cost? Let's say that we allowed anyone to create passwords containing `€` chars. Hurray, we are able to use special characters in our passwords. But wait - how on earth we can type that password if we want to get the access to our bank from a mobile-phone? It's easier to type `€` from our keyboard than from a mobile phone.

What about holidays? We are in the UK, which only has access to the UK-keyboard. Instead of `€` we can easily type `£`. The word "easily" is very important here. For some average users, typing that character on the "new" keyboard could be a problem. How will they try to solve it? They will probably call bank-support to ask them to change the password or ask why the `€` character disappeared from the keyboard.

Comment: This is a problem anyway, how easy is it to type your English password on a Chinese or Arabic keyboard, as for my phone, all those characters you asked for are immediately accessible in uk layout mode. Switching the layout on the OS and pressing the same pair of keys works whatever the markings on the key caps are.

Comment: I know it's just conjecture, but the type of user who can't figure out how to re-type their password and believes the key "disappeared" from the keyboard is probably not making clever passwords with special characters, but using ones like `goldfish2`.

Comment: Absolute bullshit. If you create a password with the arbitrary characters then it's only _you_ who should care about how to retype such a password. It was your own decision after all! **Any type of input should be allowed as a password, with any sane length**, especially with such an important things like the bank account. We're hashing this passwords/passphrases anyway, there's absolutely no point in restricting the charset. It's a total madness.

Comment: A restriction (whether it is forbidding the use of special chars or making them mandatory) does not make things easier for the user. If nothing else, it will make some users unable to use their “usual” password and force them to create/remember another one (which you might find desirable for other reasons but it is still objectively annoying and as such not “easy”).

Comment: This is the sole reason I haven't tried to change my passwords to 私は何か and other non-ASCII variations.  I can't guarantee I'll be able to enter it wherever I need to

Comment: @hijarian unfortunately, what you write there makes for a very unpopular PR slogan. We can argue about security ideals all day but at the end of the day if the user can't log into their bank account then the system has failed to do what it was supposed to. Is this a good reason to restrict the printiable ASCII characters found on nearly every keyboard worldwide? No. Is this a good reason to prevent people from using Unicode? Maybe

Comment: @DreamConspiracy "Allow to use Unicode" is not the same as "force to use Unicode". If you personally don't care, just use 7-bit ASCII, I'm what, against that somehow?

One of the goal of a good password is to make it harder for a cracker to guess it, or even better, to reproduce. If I insert just a single character outside of Unicode BMP my password becomes basically unguessable for a common bruteforce/dictionary software. I'm totally willing to inconvenience myself with finding a way to type this character for this level of security. Don't know whether it's a good PR slogan, though.

Comment: @hijarian my comment was not written because of concern for you and your ability to type out your password. It was written because of the millions of other users who do not even know the difference between printable ascii and unicode and who will suffer because the system allowed them to make the mistake of using unicode characters. This is especially relevant because its not like its asking you to sacrifice any security in the real world: If you use a password manager generated high entropy password, you do not even need non-alphanumeric characters to get over 150 bits of entropy.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy Again, my point since the beginning was this combination of words you use: "will suffer because the system allowed them to make the mistake of using unicode characters". For some reason you think about the system allowing usage of unicode characters as something bad. If the user _could enter the unicode character in the first place_, maybe they have means to enter it again in some future, no? What am I missing for it to be not true? Also, by that logic, let's prohibit the unicode in usernames as well, then, including email addresses - same problem applies to them, too.

Comment: @ewanm89 FYI: There is no such thing as "a Chinese keyboard". A keyboard that can type Chinese is still a keyboard with 26 alphabet buttons and 10 number buttons and shift and ctrl and so on. It is mostly, if not always, the software input method, not the hardware, that determines your language. And operating systems (or the IME) typically won't even let you switch to a non-latin language when typing passwords.

Comment: @SOFe not quite accurate, but I will agree that they are not common or standard, prototypes do exist of vast keyboards with lots of buttons: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Large_chinese_keyboard.jpg

The point is languages and input methods vary so much one can't be sure.

Comment: There are tens of thousands of Chinese characters. You can't even print them all in two dictionary pages.

Answer (score 11):

This can be (weakly) justified as a defense-in-depth measure - if there is an injection or other data interpretation bug, limiting the password character set and length may be able to prevent it from being exploitable. It also somewhat simplifies implementation, since if they only deal with 7-bit ASCII characters, Unicode and multibyte character string handling is irrelevant, and simpler implementations are as a rule less likely to contain bugs.

However, assessing this decreased risk against the increased risk due to lower password quality is not simple - I would expect that as the number of users of a system increases, the number of passwords that could be compromised also increases, making an investment in lifting such restrictions more worthwhile. All that said, most users' passwords will be terrible even if the field is completely unrestricted.

Comment: Ya, or just convert the password to hex or base64 encoding before storing it in the DB...  The password is the single most important security feature.  Probably ought to be worth doing it right.  Honestly, the only part of the password the DB should see anyways is a hash which is always pure binary.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is the policy exists for all user-inputed fields and the same user input policy (no special characters) was applied to fields including passwords for simplicity.  Or at some point some bank wasn't hashing passwords and had an SQLi attack through their password field, and a policy was decided that passwords can't have special characters (and the reason for the policy was forgotten once hashing was introduced).

There definitely is a security benefit of not allowing special characters in other user-inputted fields that are not hashed and could be used for various attacks like SQLi or XSS (on a bank administrator looking at an  account).  However, these threats are generally solved by always using bound parameters in SQL and always sanitizing user-input before displaying/saving to db.

My other guess is that they want to have custom rules that may be different from other places, so you can't easily reuse your standard strong password (which may get lost), and have to come up with something unique for their site.

---

EDIT: On further thought, depending on the language I can think of at least three special ASCII characters that should universally be forbidden/stripped as allowing them only tempts fate.  Specifically: `\0` (null - ascii 0), since it is customarily used to indicate end of string in C-style languages (possibly users to alter the memory after the end of the string).  Also carriage returns and line feeds `\r` (ascii 13) and `\n` (ascii 10), as these are often system dependent whether line breaks are `\r\n` or `\n` and that brings up the inevitable I can only login on from windows not my mac/linux machine.  In fact, it seems quite reasonable to only allow [printable ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) (32-126) and ban the non-printable ASCII 0-31 and 127.

But if by special characters you mean unicode not ASCII characters (like `,./<>?;':"[]{}\|!@#$%^&*(-=_+` it seems reasonable for simplicity of implementation from multiple operating systems/keyboards/browsers to not allow special characters.  Imagine your password had a lowercase pi in it.  Was that the Greek pi (π) which is codepoint 0x3c0 or the Coptic lowercase pi (ⲡ) which is codepoint 0x2ca1 -- only one will work and this type of problem of similar characters with different codepoints will exist in unicode.  Your hash which operates on bits will not be able to equate the two π, so if you try logging in different places you may input different characters.

Similarly, though this problem is one the programmer can largely control and attempt to do correct, allowing unicode characters creates encoding issues.  That is for your basic ascii characters everything is represented in a one byte number.  However, there are a bunch of different schemes for how to encode unicode.  Is it UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, Latin-1 (iso-8859-1), Latin-N encoding, and (for some encodings) what's the byte order (little or big endian)?  The unicode codepoint for pi (0x3c0) would be represented as bytes `2b 41 38 41 2d` in UTF-7, `CF 80` in UTF-8, `FF FE c0 03` in UTF-16, and `FF FE 00 00 c0 03 00 00` in UTF-32.  You wouldn't be able to represent pi in Latin-1 (it only has 95 extra printable characters), but if you had an `A1` in your password and were in different encodings you may have to represent it from any of the following characters `¡ĄĦЁ‘ก”Ḃ` (which in some Latin-N may to A1).

Yes, the webpage may have a charset defined, but users can override the charset on a page in their browser or have copied and pasted data from elsewhere in a different encoding.  At the end of the day, it may be simpler to just forbid those characters.

Comment: Almost every financial institution which stores data related to your personal information and your cash had got strict security audit, which should be repeated after any significant change in the system. So it's hard to believe in information from your second paragraph.

Comment: p___h - your comment makes no sense. Part of a security audit will look for things like bound parameters etc

Comment: @p____h Financial institutions tend to be the ones to make up there own rules and regulations to audit against, and it's not always best practices. It also tends to be up to them when they repeat any audits.

Comment: Shouldn't be there any regulations when this institutions want to collect any personal data? AFAIK, not everyone could process personal data, you need to have permission for that and follow regulations, when you want to process them (or maybe it depends on country).

Comment: @p____h - It's called [defense-in-depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing\)) and is considered a best security practice.  If you start letting people have user-fields (say a comment) like `<script src='example.com/xss.js'>` while your system should be able to fully handle it securely in all places; there's a non-zero chance some edge case/new change slipped through.  So its not a bad practice to either just strip characters like `<` from all user data prior to being saved in a db (or at least convert to html escaped characters like `&lt`).

Comment: @dr jimbob Sure, but you don't need to be stripping such data on passwords that are going straight into hashing algorithm. Or are you emailing plaintext passwords back out for your forgotten password system?

Comment: @ewanm89 - Agree.  Silently stripping characters out of passwords is an idiotic practice.  Silently stripping characters out of other fields (like comments), and forbidding special characters in passwords (not allowing at password creation time) is a reasonable practice.  A password hash acts on a bit level, and should never be stored in a database or in any code besides `hash_from_login = bcrypt_hash(pw); constant_time_str_cmp(hash_from_login, hash_from_db)`.

Comment: @drjimbob "_Silently stripping characters out of other fields (like comments),_" why? Can't you just indicate "your comment includes of these characters (...) which are not allowed"?

Comment: @curiousguy Stripping unsafe chars out of **comments** is one security tactic and showing errors would be UX choice and has minimal effect on security.  However, passwords should **never** have chars silently removed, but it happens.  A friend on one of the big US cell phone companies found out when using a password recovery feature, that (a) his password was stored in plaintext (it was emailed it to him) and (b) they silently removed all the special characters (like `!@#$%^&*()` type characters; not even unicode ones) from his password.  (He complained and left that provider over it.)

Comment: @curiousguy - though in general its often good to just properly handle questionable characters (`&` to `&amp;`; `<` to `&lt;`) versus stripping.  And its usually good not to give your attackers error messages that may be too informative; as that often helps them work around them.  But if someone managed to include say null ASCII (`\0`) characters in user-inputted fields (e.g., modify the post request to insert `%00`) I see no reason to warn them, you can't insert this character versus flag the account for an admins attention and silently remove the null character.

Comment: @drjimbob I agree that there is no legitimate reason for a user to include a `NUL` in any text field, and that if one is included it is either an accidental manipulation (f.ex copy-and-paste from a file containing `NUL` separated strings), a real attack, or a test (as in pentest). In either case, dropping the offending byte is acceptable. OTOH, when I enter quotes in a comment field, if the quotes are silently dropped, I would consider it is at least a bug (at worst a misfeature, and an offending one).

Answer (score 5):

As a generalization, here are the most common reasons that financial institutions restrict length and character set complexity.

(1) The web services are front-end systems to legacy mainframe applications, which often have an eight character limitation made up of only small case alpha and numbers. No "special characters." Oddly this is the most common limitation. +1 to Mark Burnett above.

(2) They are not hashing the passwords, so they can't simply store a fixed length numeric string (i.e. the hash output - 32 bytes of SHA256(password)). As such they have to worry about limiting the size of the input.

(3) The SQL injection threat vector is only a password issue if the passwords are stored as clear text. Many organizations and others are wasting time worrying about escaping the characters of the password, when the problem is immediately resolved by storing a hashed password (ideally *salted* and *stretched* using something like PBKDF2).

Other than favoring simple customer support password resets OVER security, there is NO acceptable reason that I am aware of for transmitting a user password in clear text off of the user's device.  You don't want the liability, so never accept them.  That's what crypto hashes are for.

Here is a great blog post that summarizes some of the best practices and includes code samples.  http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: I wouldn't consider hashing a password a solution to SQL injection.  If you have code that would be vulnerable without hashing the input, you're in trouble.  Not all inputs are passwords.  The problem is immediately resolved by using bind variables with prepared statements.

Comment: He's specifically referring to passwords in this case, though... so... hashing is absolutely a solution to SQL injection on the password field ALONG WITH prepared statements.

Comment: SQL injection can be thwarted with prepared statements regardless of how the passwords are stored. Without prepared statements you're risking introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities regardless of how the passwords are stored. Passwords are not the problem with SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

I actually asked a big webshop that (bol.com, not sure if they are international).

Their advice is to use a strong password, change it frequently, use letters and numbers, that it should be long, and maybe some other things I forgot. Anyway, the usual advice that *nobody* follows. But they seem to care about the password policy.

Yet they don't allow most special characters, and the maximum password length is 12 characters. Upon asking, they told me that otherwise too many people would contact support.

When I mailed them back to ask what the "Forgot your password?" feature was for, I got no reply...

So for banks, where a simple password reset by e-mail is out of the question, I guess support costs are really the reason (like suggested by others here). For any other website like this bol.com, I would highly distrust whether they hash their passwords. You should use a more unique password there, if the database leaks your password is going to be known.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the character set to alphanumerics limits the likelihood of a script or exploit getting past the input validation stage.

The user can always improve their security by using longer passwords, but the application needs to have a specific whitelist to help prevent attacks.

Comment: (Because I'm sure this will come up...) Isn't there a better way to protect against such scripts/exploits, while still allowing special characters in passwords?

Comment: Why would you need to validate the password at all if you just hash it before working with it?

Comment: And it allows a targeted attack to limit it's scope and decreases the entropy of possible passwords. Surely the input validation on passwords should be the full character set and it should pass straight into a hashing algorithm?

Comment: @Iszi - definitely, but this is *easy*

Comment: What Rory said. Yes, if you handle your characters correctly by always using the right kind of escaping, you are safe. But that requires coders who know what they're doing, and they are in short supply in the financial industry. Much easier to take the quick, crap fix.

Comment: *The user can always improve their security by using longer passwords*: That is not true in a case of a bank (the OP is asking about his bank) where password lengths are limited. As for the first short paragraph you wrote, while it can be true for other websites as an awkward method to prevent what you said, it is unlikely to be true with a bank which has a set of authentication methods to reinforce the security of their users. Personally I rather agree with @p____h's  answer -even after the bad comment he received-

Answer (score 0):

I can try to give my view of the problem above as a UI interface designer and not a programmer: the key point here is that the login requirement is partly a UI interface design problem and not a programming only problem.

There's an excellent book "Apress - User Interface Design for Programmers" which shows an analogous problem related to window sizes which I'll post below:

> Here's a common programmer thought pattern: there are only three
>   numbers: 0, 1, and n. If n is allowed, all n's are equally likely.
>   This thought pattern comes from the old coding convention (probably
>   smart) that you shouldn't have any numeric constants in your code
>   except for 0 and 1.

Now the thinking above is correct in a programming only problem, but as it concerns user interfaces and especially windows it isn't

> But it's not true. As it turns out, it's not equally likely. There are
>   many good reasons why you might want a window exactly at the top of
>   the screen (it maximizes screen real estate), but there really aren't
>   any reasons to leave two pixels between the top of the screen and the
>   top of the window. So, in reality, 0 is much more likely than 2.

Now coming to our problem, theoretically all characters should be equally likely and equally permitted from a programming and formal point of view, however here we are also in a UI interface problem instance and we must be aware of it and give the correct weight to it.

So I'll paraphrase an answer from the thread above which in my opinion is correct:

> Let's say that we allowed anyone to create passwords which contain the €
>   char. Hurray, we are able to use special characters in our passwords.
>   But wait - how on earth can we type that password if we want to get
>   access to our bank from the mobile-phone? It's easier to type €
>   from our keyboard than from the mobile phone.

That's the main point from a usability point of view and we shouldn't blame it on the user if he realizes some years later with a smartphone when years before they didn't even exist, that he used a character he should have avoid.

It's our obligation to think about this type of problems and let the user avoid it!

Comment: Your last hilighted paragraph is good, but must of the preceding text seems largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party - I recently read that the reason for this is that for many banks, the value of the increased security of allowing those characters is outweighed by the implementation cost and the support cost of dealing with customers that cannot remember their passwords.

I'm not saying that its a good reason, but that is how I interpreted what I read.

http://www.theglobeandmail.com/technology/digital-culture/why-canadas-banks-have-weaker-passwords-than-twitter-or-google/article18325257/

Comment: Since it's actually easier to increase security by increasing the _length_ of the password, somebody is fooling themself.  The kind of people likely to use special characters are probably less likely to forget them, too...

Comment: Isn't this covered by p____h's answer?

Answer (score -1):

One more reason! Some special characters change their location based on the keyboard used. For example, the at mark (@) and the asterisk (*) are on different keys in a mixed US-EN and Japanese language keyboard environment. If I had a dime for every time a user got locked out because they were on the wrong type of keyboard scheme... well, I'd have about a dollar or so, but you get the point.

Comment: So you're saying the user should not be allowed to use any characters other than `a` and `m` because he might be using a dvorak keyboard layout by accident.

Comment: @SOFe: Someone who had the wrong alphabetic set selected would likely notice fairly quickly during normal use.  Someone who used a keyboard layout that was fairly "normal" except that some special characters were in weird spots wouldn't notice unless they typed those special characters *into a field that would make them observable*.