# How to tell if window is from system or malicious program on macOS? (slack helper)

Tags: macos

On macOS Sierra, I am getting this popup asking me to enter my administrator's username and password in order to install some "Slack helper tool".

[image]

- How do I know this popup is from my system and not from some
  malicious program?
- It appears at random times.
- When the popup is
  active no other app is "selected" in the Dock.
- When I look at the
  processes in Activity Monitor the popup does not seems to have it's
  own process while there are already several "Slack Helper" processes
  running.

If this is legit it seems like a terrible design to me.

*EDIT:* Even if I identified the process of the window, how could I know the process is from the system? Unlike in Window's task manager, all the processes in the Activity Monitor are from "User" myself.

Comment: In Activity Monitor there is an option under the view menu to see processes from all users.

Comment: I agree with checking the process name in activity monitor, but as a first sanity-check step I'd look in the upper left hand corner of your screen and make sure the popup belongs to a plausible app (ie not Safari or something in which case it's likely phishing)

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/167412/61443

Answer (score 1):

The popup certainly looks like a legitimate one. To be certain you would want to verify to which process it belongs and from there verify you trust the underlying executable.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/939476/299330) shows one way to identify the process for the window. The ps command should allow you to find the underlying executable.

> If this is legit it seems like a terrible design to me.

The ability of applications to fake OS input fields is a known issue. There is ongoing work to find better ways to perform tasks like this.

Comment: "The popup certainly looks like a legitimate one" - based on what? 
And what would prevent me from creating an identical popup?

Comment: Even if I identified the process of the window, how would I know the process is from the system?

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek - in that that is exactly what a legitimate popup does look like. As stated at the bottom it is trivially easy to imitate this. As for your "all processes" comment its on the view menu for Activity Monitor or you can use "ps aux".