# Is checking the Referer and Origin headers enough to prevent CSRF, provided that requests with neither are rejected?

Tags: csrf

Is it possible to prevent CSRF by checking the Origin and Referer headers?  Is this adequate, provided that requests with neither are blocked?

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413930/is-checking-the-referrer-enough-to-protect-against-a-csrf-attack) on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Expanding on the answers of @Sjoerd and @lindon.

---

#### `Origin` vs `Referer` vs CSRF token

Most likely, the reason OWASP recommends also using a CSRF token, is that at the time when this recommendation was made - a significant portion of browsers did not yet support the `Origin` header. This is no longer the case, but [people are chimpanzees](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33471).

In order to preserve privacy, any browser request can decide to omit the `Referer` header. So it is probably best to only check the `Origin` header. (In case you want to allow for users to preserve their privacy)

The `Origin` header is [null in some cases](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Origin#Privacy-Sensitive_Contexts).
Note that all of these requests are GET requests, which means they should not have any side effects.

As long as you make sure the malicious website sending the requests with your browser cannot read the responses, you should be fine. This can be ensured using proper CORS headers. (Do not use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`!)

To prevent "click-jacking", set the header `X-Frame-Options: DENY`. This will tell your browser that it is not allowed to display any part of your website in an iframe.

---

#### The "new" approach

Setting Cookie properties `SameSite=lax` or `SameSite=strict` will prevent CSRF attacks. This is a quite new feature though, and cannot be used alone, simply for the reason that not all common browsers support it yet. You can track support [HERE](https://caniuse.com/#search=SameSite).

When the browsers do, people will likely still recommend checking Origin/Referer/CSRF tokens. If they do - without giving a good reason, it is likely because they are chimps.

Comment: according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin#Browser_compatibility), Edge doesn't send the `Origin` header with `POST` requests

Comment: @Razor: That is a very good point! Edge 16-18 does support the SameSite cookie property. Those using Edge 12-15 (0.13% globally at the time of this comment) would be vulnerable to CSRF attacks for websites not using tokens.

Comment: It also appears that this is an opt-in feature in Firefox, and is available only since version 59. [Source.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin#Browser_compatibility) However, this is addressable by just disallowing Origin-less requests altogether, and using JavaScript for form submission. Not optimal, but good enough.

Comment: Beware that Origin header is not always sent for requests on the same origin.

Comment: @TobiasBergkvist A bit of respect for chimpanzees, please. `SameSite` is only meant as a defense-in-depth measure precisely because it doesn't prevent all types of _cross-origin_ abuse: https://jub0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/

Comment: GET requests can leak data which is just as damaging as request causing a modification. For example, if a website stores your information as an image. And evil.com makes has `<img src='bankapp.com/info.jpg' />` then origin headers wont be sent, depending on browser/samesite policy cookies thus session might be sent.

Comment: Consider also an attack where the request is actually sent from the same site, by user-generated content. Not technically "cross-site" request forgery I guess, but still request forgery that CSRF tokens can protect against (since you can't create a crafted URL), I think.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, the image will be displayed, but Same Origin Policy will prevent javascripts from reading the image contents.  Only the image width and height will be available.

Comment: SameSite with lax cannot protect against all csrf attacks. 
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-02#section-5.3.7.1

From the link:
1. "Attackers can still pop up new windows or trigger top-level navigations in order to create a "same-site" request"

2. "Features like "<link rel='prerender'>" [prerendering] can be exploited to create "same-site" requests without the risk of user detection."

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is secure.

However, the referer header is not exactly mandatory, so there may be browsers or proxies than don't send a referer header. This would mean that these clients can't access your web site.

With the introduction of [referrer policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) it is possible to remove the referer header from a forged request. So to protect against CSRF it is necessary to block any requests that are missing a referer (and origin) header.

Edit: [This paper](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/csrf/csrf.pdf) has some numbers on what portion of clients omit a referer header.

Comment: What about referer header and HTTPS? If site is hosted on HTTP and CSRF is initiated from HTTPS site, there will be no referer header to check.

Comment: If site is hosted on HTTP then you are insecure be definition.

Comment: I think one could construct a case where even a non-zero Referer should not be trusted: If the target site T contains a link to some external site X (or embeds a resource like an image from this site, e.g. an avatar) and an attacker can make modifications to site X then the request from site T to site X (containing a Referer from T) could be answered with a HTTP redirect back to site T but with some malicious action in the URL. In this case T sees a request with a Referer of T and trusts it, even though the target URL at T is controlled by X.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That is an excellent point! Of course, GET requests should be idempotent so that it doesn't matter if they're "forged" because they don't change any state, but people mess that one up all the time (including expecting POST requests but allowing GETs to that endpoint as well).

Comment: Why checking `Origin``header alone is not enough? And also, by checking these headers, do you mean validating that the requests `Origin` header matches the ones you whitelisted in the application?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer covered most of the things already. However, there is special case where you still need CSRF token even if you SameSite=strict is enable.

For example, website A lets users post contents and embed image source from wherever they want. Then, malicious user can insert an image with `src=website-a.com/remove/something`. This image is shown in website A, therefore, when normal users browse to this image, request initiated from this image is same origin with website A.

One problem is, request initiated from image a GET request, most action APIs are POST. However, Malicious user can often convert request from POST to GET and server still accept it, which makes CSRF attack possible.

Comment: In this case do you need a CSRF token or do you need to ensure that GET requests don't change state? Seems like either would suffice and that the latter might be preferable, especially since [frameworks like ASP.NET Core don't validate the antiforgery token by default on GET requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.autovalidateantiforgerytokenattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0#definition).

Comment: @ChaseMedallion, we need to ensure GET requests don't change state. Because if they do, there are more problems than just CSRF. For example, rate-limiting protection usually works with POST requests only. If attacker can change state with GET requests. They can bypass rate-limit and spam servers with heavy loads.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rely on the Origin header to prevent XSRF, I suggest deploying the front-end and back-end application on different origins like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and api.example.com. In this case, the Origin header should be included with every modern browser. In addition, api.example.com can then reject any request with a missing Origin header.

If the above separation is not possible, i.e. because front-end and back-end is one application, a missing Origin header probably needs to be allowed by the server to prevent breaking the application (since the Origin headers is missing for same origin requests). Such a policy would then allow cross origin XSRF requests with very old browsers not attaching the Origin header. But at least victims with a modern browser should still be safe.

Also consider using CORS in combination with non simple requests for any critical request to prevent XSRF.