# What is the most up-to-date secure method for storing .ENV variables?

Tags: encryption, web-application, php, webserver, configuration

I am improving the security on my php website. I am not using any frameworks or cms. The credentials are currently stored in plain text in the relevant php files. While researching, I came across this question [Why use .ENV? What's wrong with storing secrets in a config.php file outside root directory?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199248/why-use-env-whats-wrong-with-storing-secrets-in-a-config-php-file-outside-roo?newreg=b71c58eec21c4663b038cd5223658031)

The first answer by *Schwern* makes the argument that .ENV variables are fine and

> ".ENV is a convenience and, ideally, **is not used in production**"

I do not have the reputation to comment so can anyone explain what should "ideally" be used in production?

Answer (score 1):

> The first answer by Schwern makes the argument that .ENV variables are fine and
>
> > ".ENV is a convenience and, ideally, is not used in production"

Before that line, you skipped this line:

> To clarify, the security and flexibility are gained by putting secrets into environment variables.

If you're not comfortable using `.ENV`, then just pass the credentials as environment variables. `.ENV` is just a convenience around environment variables.

> The credentials are currently stored in plain text in the relevant php files

From a security POV, storing credentials in a plain text vs. passing them as environment variables is functionally equivalent. You're not making your website more secure by making this change.

---

The context for that question was storing plain-text secrets *in the code repository* vs. passing them through `.ENV`, and which approach was more secure. Unless your situation is similar, that answer is irrelevant

Comment: https://phptherightway.com/#configuration_files It would be nice if there were more explicit standards for handling credentials in production. Wordpress encrypts the credentials in the wp-config file, is it worth attempting to implement something similar? At first glance it's confusing how the db password is decrypted for db operations.

Comment: Seems that just proper file permissions should do the trick. Have a look here: https://artisansweb.net/correct-file-permissions-wordpress/

Comment: thanks for the link. Sorry if I'm being obtuse but I'm not following how file permissions relate to the question or comment. I understand storing plaintext credentials is acceptable in a config file as long as permissions are set appropriately. Is that what you're referring to?  I haven't had a chance to research how wp decrypts user passwords and it's not clear from the code.

Comment: Yes, storing plaintext credentials is acceptable in a config file as long as permissions are set appropriately *on said config file*. And no need to apologize;
this is a Q&A site, and you're asking a question :)