# Why use random characters in passwords?

Tags: passwords, account-security

I've seen some similar questions but maybe not exactly what I'm asking. Also I can't say that I've followed all the technical jargon in previous posts and am really after more of an intuitive understanding.

So let's say I'm allowed ten characters. The usual requirement is to use numbers, symbols, etc. But why is `#^Afx375Zq` more secure than `aaaaaaaaaa`? The hacker doesn't know that I've repeated a character ten times, so doesn't he still have to go through the testing of all possibilities or are things like repeated characters tested first?

Similarly, suppose I use a 21-character passphrase such as

```
I like Beatles' songs.
```

Now someone might say that that's a common type of statement but again the hacker doesn't know that I'm using a passphrase instead of

```
DD63@*()ZZZ125++dkeic
```

so why is it (I assume) less secure? Are passphrases tested first?

Comment: a 5 pin tumbler lock with all the same pin heights can be opened with a screwdriver, despite holding as many "secrets" as a random-height lock cylinder.

Comment: Always a good idea to start your password hacking attempts with a password database full of passwords that have been leaked before (see haveibeenpwned.com). Maybe you really did memorize some awesome `Z"45nty@w#` password. Maybe even no other human ever used that password; it's great, but hard to remember 100 like it, so you reuse it.. Then some site you used it on got hacked, and let your password escape in plain text: Now means your awesome password that only you ever used is just there, in a DB, waiting to  be tried.. Now imagine how many humans ever used aaaaaaaaaa as a password anywhere

Comment: Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/712551/how-are-pseudorandom-and-truly-random-numbers-different-and-why-does-it-matter/712583#712583

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you were to generate a totally random password that is 10 letters long and can contain lower and upper case letters, numbers and common symbols, then you are equally likely to come up with **#^Afx375Zq** as you are **aaaaaaaaaa**. So from that point of view you're right that the passwords are equally secure.

However, most passwords are not generated randomly. They are chosen by humans, and humans don't pick a completely random series of characters. They choose something that they will be able to remember, and clearly the second password is much easier to remember than the first.

Therefore, if you take a large enough database of user accounts, you are likely to find that far more of them have chosen your second password than your first. As an attacker I can use that knowledge, so I'll test easy to remember passwords first.

Comment: Indeed, for a password to be secure you want it to be secure even if your attacker knows the process you chose for generating the password.

Answer (score 63):

The strength of a password is determined by its scheme. A code like `aaaaaaaaaa` must be assumed to have a scheme of "ten letters" and is therefore trivially cracked compared to the scheme we must assume from `#^Afx375Zq`.

Attackers prioritize the simplest arrangement that meets the password scheme: start with a capital letter, end with a number and then punctuation, fill the middle with the minimum lowercase letters, starting with words as sorted by frequency. I have such a dictionary, so I could start with `Anything0!` through `Zzzombie9~`, then progress to the non-word combinations of `Aaaaaaaa0!` through `Zzzzzzzz9~` before different variations.

Ensuring your password is more complex than the minimally permissible code gives you a slight advantage; `#aaaaaaaaa` should take a few minutes longer to crack as `aaaaaaaaaa`. `#^Afx375Zq` will take a good amount longer because it mixes four classes of characters and only uses three lowercase letters.

Always assume attackers know your scheme. You may get lucky and be able to hide behind some obscurity, which is certainly worthwhile, but it must not factor into your math. Don't try to be "clever"—[Kaspersky's attempt at this ended in failure](https://zdnet.com/article/kaspersky-password-manager-caught-out-making-easily-bruteforced-passwords/); they made assumptions about the attack order that ended up creating *much* weaker passwords.

Forcing users to add complexity to the characters in their passwords forces attackers to increase the complexity of their brute-force attacks, though it actually *weakens* the overall entropy. It prevents lazy and easily-guessed passwords like `aaaaaaaaaa` by removing them from the possible password list. There are 94⁸ possible eight-character passwords (60 quintillion, entropy = 52), yet requiring a lower, upper, number, and special reduce that to 26×26×10×32×94⁴ (16 trillion, entropy = 43).

`I like Beatles' songs.` is neither random nor unique. Unsurprisingly, Google has hits for it.

[***If a Google query for your password (quoted & de-0bfuscated) might get hits, it is weak.***](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/257111/42391)

**Passwords must actually be random** ([not arbitrary! not obscure!](https://twitter.com/adamhotep/status/1234631623322324993) a [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) is okay), by characters (for passcodes) or by words (for passphrases). `I like Beatles' pants.` is more unique, but it's arbitrary, not random. You cannot "make up" a random phrase without assistance (ideally using a generator), only one that *seems* random. It's okay to generate several phrases and pick one that you can make a creative story around.

I [calculated](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93628/42391) a word is worth 2.5 characters, so for equivalent entropy to a passcode with 10 random characters, log₂(94¹⁰) = 65, you'd need a passphrase with 4 random words, log₂(100000⁴) = 66. That's on the weaker side, and again: a passphrase that is a sentence is *not* secure.

**Length isn't everything.** Don't be fooled by the impressive length of a passphrase. Sure, your musical preference is 21 characters, but even if we assume it's random and not known to Google, it's four words with some punctuation thrown in: log₂(100000⁴×32²) = 76. Compare that to random lowercase letters: log₂(26²¹) = 98. Compare those to random characters: log₂(94²¹) = 137.

**A summary of [my password advice](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/257595/42391):**
The world has gotten sophisticated enough that it's impossible to remember your fully-random and unique-per-account passwords (be they codes or phrases).

- Use authenticator apps for 2FA or passwordless access when available
- Use a password manager to generate and save passwords
- Lock your password manager with a strong password with 90+ bits of entropy,
  say with a generated 4char code randomly placed within a generated 4word phrase,
  entropy = log₂(100000⁴×94⁴×5) = 94, like `junkie unknotted 7!cT opposite litter`.
  Make a story to remember the words and keep the 4char code in your wallet if needed.

Comment: This thread has been very instructive. A followup question if I may. (I know most people would recommend a password manager but I'm trying to understand the basics here). Suppose you use an English phrase but insert a random character into it so for instance using the above example:  I like ^ Beatles' songs . Does that significantly improve its security?

Comment: @Not_Einstein Every permutation adds more complexity to it. The question then becomes "How many permutations is an attacker willing to try?" The general rule of thumb is "The more, the better". For a password you have to remember (e.g. Bitlocker PIN), try to be as random as you can, e.g. `TmWouIomB4HBlMs.hzRv` instead of `ILike_The_Beatlez123`

Comment: There are 32 special characters, so log₂(100000⁴×32³) upgrades a _random_ 3word + 2special passphrase from 76 to 81 bits of entropy, but **let's not forget that phrase is not random**. Let's err on the side of saying it's worth 34 (valuing the first word as "random", log₂(100000) = 16, plus each additional word as a random alphanumeric, log₂(62³) = 6×3 = 18). `I like ^ Beatles' songs.` is therefore still a weak 49 (or 51 if you say the `^` was added to a random location around the 4 words). You're half way there; see my [password advice](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/257595/42391).

Comment: Picking nits: while excluding passwords (because they're "too simple") lowers entropy, your formula assumes `lUd&` must appear at the beginning, in that order, so you're underestimating entropy a bit there. (But all three in-my-head tries at corrective terms were too simplistic as well.)

Comment: Could you tell me how something is "truly random" I don't think that's possible with computers or dictionaries

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz – I can't find `lUd&` anywhere on this page but your comment and the only time I have accounted for order in my entropy calculations is when the order was explicitly determined by an additional random number. Low-balling entropy is always a good thing .

Comment: @Tvde1 – Good point, I didn't mean "true random" in the technical sense. Corrected. A password generator's [PRNGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) should suffice here. The effort needed for an attacker to replicate the seed and deterministic RNG is extremely high, though some people prefer [hardware RNGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) or [Diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware). See also ["True" vs. pseudo-random numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#%22True%22_vs._pseudo-random_numbers).

Comment: "Complexity matters, not length" is wrong. Both matter. A 5 character password with an upper, lower, punctuation, number, and special character is NOT stronger than a 16 character password consisting only of letters and numbers.

Comment: @barbecue – I'm using "complexity" as a more user-friendly synonym of "entropy". Length is a component of complexity; a 5-char password is not very complex. The math in my answer agrees with you, that these extra requirements dilute the entropy/complexity. If you think that needs clarification, I can adjust my answer.

Comment: @AdamKatz I see what you mean, but the the word "complexity" has been widely used to mean the use of special characters and mixed case, without reference to length. Admin UIs, explanations of password security on login pages, and even the UIs of various password managers all use it this way. I'm not sure what a better word would be though.

Comment: Maybe  "unpredictability"...

Comment: @barbecue – I have replaced ambiguous uses of the term "complexity" with "strength" as a more user-friendly synonym of "entropy" ("Complexity matters, not length" now reads "Length isn't everything"). Length and variety of character are obviously both important, though forced variety without increasing length does dilute entropy, as noted in my answer.

Comment: I would add that replacing a word with a shortened version does not reduce its entropy by much. For example, "clustermuck" and "clstrmk" have similar entropy, but the second is faster to type. So I would recommend to use shortened words and add one more word: overall the passphrase would be faster to type, stronger and as easy to remember.

Comment: Passphrases that are sentences can be secure, you just need to generate them randomly.  "Sacred isolation melts considerably amazing rain" and "human maths rock possibly overwhelming movement" are perfectly good passphrases -- or were, until I posted them in this comment.

Comment: @Mark – If you have access to a random sentence generator, go for it. If you're using a random generator to select words and then add more words to make sentences out of them, you may accidentally undo the randomness by forming sentence fragments that are less unique.

Comment: Here you go: `shuf -n 1 adjectives.txt; shuf -n 1 nouns.txt; shuf -n 1 verbs.txt; shuf -n 1 adverbs.txt;shuf -n 1 adjectives.txt; shuf -n 1 nouns.txt`.  Given the wordlists I'm using, that's 60 bits of entropy.

Comment: Counter point: *If you make a Google query for your password (quoted & de-0bfuscated) then you make it weaker*. By willingly typing your password into search engines, you willingly give them your password (as well as your identifiable data of who made the search). While Google will neither hack you nor compile a "here is a list of all searches which looks like passwords", they will sell their data and there is always a risk that your password is on one of the lists they sell.

Comment: @Mrkvička – Yes, that's why I said “might”. The point of this is the thought exercise, to remind people that very little is “novel” and that they need to use something that's actually random, not clever, arbitrary, or obscure. Also, you can use Google to test a password scheme (like any of the samples given on this page) rather than an exact prospective password.

Comment: @AdamKatz nice improvements, thanks!

Comment: What is the fourth lowercase letter in #^Afx375Zq?

Answer (score 24):

Attackers try the most common passwords first, because they're the most likely ones that will work. So they might start with things like `password` or `Password1` or common patterns such as `123456`, `1qaz2wsx` or `aaaaaaaaaa`

For example, there's a common technique called "password spraying", when rather than trying lots of passwords against one account, you try a few common passwords (such as `Password1`) against lots of different accounts. This is useful when you want to compromise *any* account, rather than having a specific target.

If they don't have success with common passwords, then they'll try increasingly uncommon things like longer words, using rules to mutate the words (such as adding numbers on the end or capitalising them), combining multiple words together, or even exhaustive brute-force attacks of shorter lengths.

One method of creating lists of potential passwords is to crawl websites for words and phrases (especially as more people have started using phrases). So a passphrase such as `I like Beatles' song.` might appear in one of these lists, because it's a phrase that might appear on the Internet somewhere. But a long random string will never appear in a wordlist (unless you post it on Stack Exchange), and 21 characters is far too long for an attacker to brute-force).

If you want to create secure passwords, the best options are either a long, random string like the one you posted (which is what most password managers do), or a series of multiple *unrelated* words. So rather than a sentence (like the example you gave), just pick four random words (such as the famous [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/936/) example of `CorrectHorseBatteryStaple`).

Comment: Is the XKCD scheme really better? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62832/is-the-oft-cited-xkcd-scheme-no-longer-good-advice

Comment: The XKCD scheme still works as well as it did because of the inherent entropy in choosing 4 terms at random from a really big list of terms.  The person saying "crackers are on to this trick" seems not to understand that even with a 20,000 word list, the crackers would still need to iterate over 20,000^4 combinations - there's no shortcut to that.
The XKCD method doesn't win out in terms of entropy *per character* but it never did and this is not what truly matters.
Where it does fail is that the number of passwords a typical person has now all but requires the use of a password manager.

Comment: @qwr I mean all the answers there say it’s still as good as it was. Why do you think the answers are wrong?

Comment: @qwr the XKCD seems to be based on choosing four words out of a list of 2,000 - but the average person's vocabulary is about ten times that (before we even account for other languages), so if anything the XKCD underestimates the strength of these passwords (they should be ~57bits rather than ~44 bits). And also, that strength only applies if an attacker knows how the password was constructed, *and* knows the exact list of 20,000 words that were used to create it. If they don't know both of those things, the passwords are even stronger.

Comment: But it's also important to remember that total entropy isn't the only attribute that matters for passwords. While you can sometimes stores them in a password manager, that's not always possible, and a huge strength of these passphrases is that *you can actually remember them*.

Comment: Also, when it absolutely positively has to be shared (or must not be fumbled) it is a lot easier to communicate and remember a passphrase. There is a reason why "all zeros" was used for tactical nukes.  What3words is a good example of what can be done.

Comment: @thomasrutter: the 'person saying that' is Bruce Schneier. You can be quite sure he perfectly understands your point. His point is that people don't choose 4 *random* words.

Comment: @Confusion if people are not choosing them at random, then they are not actually doing what XKCD method prescribes.  That's not a flaw in the XKCD method, at all.

Answer (score 1):

Most people, including lots of them who write password policies, don't actually understand passwords. Exhibit A: The original author of the "complexity" rules [is now sorry for his mistake](https://specopssoft.com/blog/father-password-rules-sorry-wasting-time/).

We now know that length is more important than complexity. We also know that you do not want your password to be:

a) something common, like 12345678 (yes, that's a very common password) which any of the available tools will try within the first five seconds.

b) something easily guessable like your dog's name that anyone somewhat familiar with you (or following you on Facebook) would try in a targeted low-effort attack.

Beyond that, fuck all the rules, they're silly. Most attacks on passwords don't brute-force. Most compromised passwords are leaked in one way or the other, in which case it really doesn't matter if your password is 123 or +)r%rARAT:Am))17z(rZk!,%ODbsz0

So why do you want to use some randomness in your passwords? Because of b) - humans are terrible at making something random or difficult to guess. Include at least a random part. Something like "I was born in (random three-digit number)" is a ton better as a password than whatever the complexity meters tell you.

Your phrase is pretty good - unless it is true. If it is true it falls under b) and trying out fifty statements each in a hundred different phrases and spellings is easily scripted.

Unless you're a high-profile target, stop worrying beyond that. You are much more likely to be compromised by software vulnerabilities than by someone spending the resources to brute-force even a mildly good password.

Comment: +1 for something guessable.  You don't want to lock your heirs and assigns out.   Especially if there is no back door and no chance of recovery.   It doesn't hurt to have an envelope in a safe either.

Comment: @mckenzm the solution to recovery is not to choose a weak password. It is to store your list of passwords in a trusted location or with a trusted person. If you want to go the extra step, split the list and give it to 2 or 3 trusted people (e.g. the first person gets the first characters, the second person the last characters) who are unlikely to come together for any other reason besides your funeral. Maybe your first and second wife or something. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Before the advent of password managers, because **people needed to be able to remember passwords**, they had a tendency to **pick simple passwords**.

Simple passwords are **extremely** common. You know, "password", "123456", "qwerty", and so on. Don't laugh, those are actually 3 of the most common passwords in use! But there are looooong **lists of common passwords**, and hackers usually start with those (**dictionary attacks**). And yes, **`aaaaaaaaaa` is in the top 10 000 most common passwords** (along with various other lengths).

So, in order to **force people to come up with something a bit different**, rules like those were introduced. Are they good rules? Apparently they do help, as none of the most common passwords contain the often required combination of lower, upper, symbol and digit.

The next issue after that is that once people have found a password which fits those rules AND they can remember, they **re-use it everywhere**, and from there you have the issue that a leak on one site will affect your accounts on all other sites where you sued the same password. This is why the current **best practice is to use password managers** (but that is not something sites can enforce, this is a user-side policy), which will generate and securely store **random** passwords for you.

If passwords are actually generated **randomly** rather than chosen by humans, then the goal is to have a level of entropy matching whatever requirements you set (in bits, or number of combinations, which is the same). There are two approaches to increase this: increase the number of possible symbols, or increase their number (or both, of course). A **random** 10-character lower-case password has roughly the same entropy as a **random** 8-character lower/upper/digit/symbol password. But if it's really random, it's nearly impossible to remember anyway, so it will end up being written down.

Phrases are an alternative. Here you replace characters by words. If you pick 4 **random** words from a 5000-word dictionary, you have again roughly the same entropy as above, and it's probably a lot easier to remember.

However, if you are not picking **random** words out of a long list, but an even easier-to-remember sentence which actually makes sense, then you fall in the same traps as with the usual passwords: are you sure the sentence you chose is not so common that it will end up in dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

Any reasonable system will prevent a cracker from repeated attempts to brute-force a password by, for example, imposing a 'lock-out' period after a few  failed attempts, or imposing a longer and longer pause after each failed attempt.

It follows that beyond a certain relatively low point, the complexity of your password is immaterial.  For example, a password that is known to be of 4 digits (ie, a PIN) can be brute-forced inside three attempts in only 0.03% of attacks. Repeated attempts at such attacks should be detected by the system or its administrator, and blocked.  Brute-force cracking is only feasible under that constraint if the system has already been compromised and the password encrypts are available to the cracker.

If the system administrator insists on a long and complex password, then that is an implicit admission that she/he has little faith in the security of the system and her/his ability to keep the password encrypts out of crackers' hands.

However, if you re-use on a high-value target the credentials (username, password)  that you have used on a system that may be cracked, then you can expect trouble.

Comment: Interesting. Do current Windows and Mac OS systems have these preventive measures?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of randomly generated passwords.

I use a password safe and randomly generated passwords. I also use my own password generator. No. I won't post it here, but you can get some good ideas from Bruce Schneier's **Applied Cryptography**. My passwords have any of 51 different characters, and each password has 16 characters. 51^16 = 2.1 x 10^27 possible passwords. A brute force attack would be exceptionally difficult for a classical computer. Perhaps a big quantum computer could get it. The down side of it, of course, is that my passwords are pure gibberish. Here's an example: 57x]Vb1R+}m2nh. Ugly, huh? I put them into a password safe and copy/paste them from there. So. You'd need to hack into my computer, run the password safe, guess that password, and you're in. Is this perfect? Probably not:

Smart people think they can come up with an unbreakable code, and the smarter they are, the more certain they are that they can do it.
-- Charles Babbage.

Finally, most security breaches are because of social engineering by clever attackers, and laxity by the defenders. Brute force attacks on a well defended system rarely succeed.

Answer (score -4):

I am not a security expert, but I feel like I need to add two points.

1. Tools that brute-force passwords will simply start at 000000 then 0000001 and aaaaaaaa is really, really easy to get in the first few seconds of that "set" of N digits. I don't know of any exact tools, but this is what I learned from ye olde tutorials on astalavista, before it became ads, and was a hacker search.
2. The top answer, which states "aaaaa" is just as likely strikes me as mathematically inaccurate. Even-distribution algorithms have a bias to not give the same thing they just did. They're not unbiased, it's just split among all numbers instead of a specific number or set of numbers.

Comment: "Tools that brute-force passwords will simply..." -- this is simply not true.

Comment: Please do not respond to answers in an answer. Simply post an answer. And your assumption about the math is incorrect, your assumption about how random generators work is incorrect, and you have misunderstood the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @schroeder, yeah, it pretty much is, most of the time.  Sequential is the most widely used.  Dictionary and Rainbow Tables will provide a better yield for donkey passwords, but hard crypto slog is still permutation based - but if broken up into a few million parallel sub ranges and scaled out it starts at a pont assigned to the work unit. Not considering collisions because they will exist. We know that truncation to save space happens, and we know that not everything gets salted.

Comment: There are plenty of tools freely available. Please go and download them. You will find that they do **not** start at 0000 or aaaa or such a thing. They start with lists of common passwords and permutations.

Comment: "most of the time. Sequential is the most widely used" -- citation needed. You have already stated that you do not really know and that your knowledge is old. I'm telling you, as an expert, and as someone who actually uses the tools, your assertion is simply wrong. Yes, there are incremental tools. They are a last resort when other, more efficient tools, fail. So, your claim is factually, and provably false on its face.